Issue Generating Access Token for SMTP Mail Server on ThingsBoard
I hope this message finds you well!
I am currently facing an issue when attempting to generate an access token for the SMTP mail server on ThingsBoard. I have double-checked that the Client ID, Client Secret, and Tenant ID in my ThingsBoard configuration match those in the Azure Portal. Additionally, the redirect URIs are correctly configured.
Despite these checks, I encounter the following error when clicking on "Generate Access Token":
Error while requesting access token: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
I carefully reviewed the following configurations:
Client ID, Client Secret, and Tenant ID: I ensured that the values entered in ThingsBoard exactly match those listed in the Azure Portal.
Redirect URIs: I confirmed that the redirect URI in the ThingsBoard application matches the one registered in Azure.
API Permissions: I checked the API permissions granted to my Azure application to ensure that all necessary permissions (such as Mail.Send and offline_access) are correctly assigned and granted.
After verifying these settings, I expected to successfully generate an access token without receiving any errors. However, I still received the 401 Unauthorized error when attempting to generate the access token.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance from the community to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!
Best regards,
Mirai.

Could you try generating the token via Postman and confirm whether it's working or not?
